# Chrome not rendering menu graphic properly

Tags: css, google-chrome

Hi all – I was wondering if anyone could offer any insight into a problem I am having, which I can't get my head around.

Check out the following left menu. When it renders Chrome, as you can see the bottom search is inconsistent visually with the other two, the "go" button hovers to the left for some reason. It works in all other browsers I have tested it in (IE8, IE9, Firefox)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/14/renderaj.jpg/

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="quickAccess" class="clearfix">

<div class="accessBox courseFinder">

<form id="course-finder" name="gs" method="GET" action="/future/course_search">
<input id="course-keyword-search-field" class="formField" type="text" title="Course Search" name="q" maxlength="256" value="">
<input class="formSearch" type="submit" name="btnG" value="GO">
<input type="hidden" name="entqr" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="ud" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sort" value="date:L:d1">
<input type="hidden" name="output" value="xml_no_dtd">
<input type="hidden" name="oe" value="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="filter" value="0">
</form>

</div><!-- end accessbox coursefinder -->

<div class="accessBox askUs">

<form action="http://cit.edu.au/images/crm/search.php" method="post" id="askUs-form">
<input id="askus-keyword-search-field" class="formField" type="text" title="AskUs Search" name="askUsKeywords"/>
<input class="formSearch" type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>

</div><!-- end accessbox askus -->

<div class="accessBox search">

<form id="site-search" name="gs" method="GET" action="/home/site_search">
<input id="site-keyword-search-field" class="formField" type="text" title="Site Search" name="q" maxlength="256" value="">
<input class="formSearch" type="submit" name="btnG" value="GO">
<input type="hidden" name="entqr" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="ud" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sort" value="date:L:d1">
<input type="hidden" name="output" value="xml_no_dtd">
<input type="hidden" name="oe" value="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="filter" value="0">
</form>

</div><!-- end accessbox search -->

</div><!-- end quick access -->
```

Comment: Where is your CSS? It is better to create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net

Comment: It might be a width inconsistency, probably due to outline property. Can you post CSS?

Comment: Is it possible to have your HTML output in the browser rather than an image? Plus, *where* is your CSS?

Comment: Sorry, here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/txRK9/

Comment: And here is the live page in question:
http://cit.edu.au/future

Answer (score 0):

---

Now i m checking now you can do this and sort out your problem

**give to your** `#site-search` to `position` and give to your button `right :0;`

```
              #site-search{
        position:relative;
        }
    #quickAccess .search input.formSearch {
    right:0;
position:absolute; // you give to already 
    }
      #quickAccess .accessBox{
      width:187px;
      }
```

**Live demo** http://tinkerbin.com/KBGMIGbi

Comment: The code given by Justin Newbury is already working in Firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: @A.K now check to live demo http://tinkerbin.com/KBGMIGbi  this is working chrome ..

Comment: @JustinNewbury now you can only add css in your css style sheet please check to my answer in above i have upadated

Comment: I appreciate your effort - and yes, the change has corrected the problem.

However now the left menu displays incorrectly in Firefox. Here is a screenshot:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/254/20212630.jpg/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to use of `position:absolute;` for `#quickAccess .accessBox input.formSearch` css make it `position:relative;`

```
#quickAccess .accessBox input.formSearch {
    border-left:1px solid;
    border-right:1px solid;
    padding:0 5px;
    height:32px;
    margin:0 0 0 -4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.2em;
    position:absolute; /*<<<<< ----- It Should be position:relative*/
    -moz-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/txRK9/4/